# Arrow with reversed head

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows

It is possible to draw an arrow, where the arrowhead is located at the right end of the arrow but pointing left (like the bottom one in the below picture)?

In particular, I am hoping to define a MathOperator (operator) that can be used just as \to.

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\ot}{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex] \draw[-to reversed] (0,0) -- (1em,0);} 


\begin{document}

    \[ a \ot b \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

What is wrong with `-<`?

[image: reversed arrow]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-<] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`TikZ` has `-<` as a built in arrow head. To get the same size and shape arrowhead of LaTeX `\to` requires the `arrows.meta` library. To get the same length as the `\to` arrow requires some tweaking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\from}{\mathrel{\tikz[>={To}, line cap=round, anchor=base] \draw[shorten <=.55pt,-<] (0,0) -- (3.375mm,0);}}

\begin{document}

$a\to b$

$a\from b$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This also will helps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(2,2)
 \psline[ArrowInside=-]{-<}(2;2)
 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
If you want to create \begin{tikzcd}
a  & [-1.4em] \arrow[l, no head, tail] b
\end{tikzcd} a text
\end{document}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
a \arrow[r] &[-1.4em] b
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]